# Pycharm code reformatting: align lines by operator

Tags: python, alignment, pycharm, text-alignment

In Jetbrains Pycharm (Professional, 2016.1), is there a way (built in or third-party) to modify the code style in python to align consecutive lines by an operator, particularly an assignment one? For example, I would like

```
var1 = 5
variable2 = 10
varbl3 = 15
```

to be reformatted to

```
var1      = 5
variable2 = 10
varbl3    = 15
```

I am aware of several packages that let me do this manually with an external command (I am currently using Front-End Alignment, but String Manupulation also works decently), but it precludes me from also using code reformatting (which I otherwise find very useful) on the same piece of code.

I am aware this does not follow PEP-8 standards, and I don't wish to have a debate about the merits/demerits of aligning code. Is there a way to allow the reformat code option to automatically take care of this for me?

Comment: There should be a way since I think android studio? has it. One of the Jetbrains suite. This is very irritating.

Answer (score 13):

To my knowledge, there isn't an automatic way.

That said, something I found very helpful is "Add multiline carets on double ⌥ (Option key) with arrow keys" (found in General>Smart Keys) along with "Move Caret to Next Word".

1. Put the cursor on line 1, double tap ⌥ and hold then press the down
   arrow the number of lines to edit.

   [image]
2. Let go of ⌥ (to get Pycharm out of 'add more cursors mode') then using "Move Caret to Next Word" ⌥→ move the cursors just before the `=` on each line.

   [image]
3. Add a bunch of spaces till all the equal signs are past the alignment point.

   [image]
4. Put the cursors back to the start of the line to get them aligned again.

   [image]
5. Move them to the alignment point.

   [image]
6. Shift ⌥ → to highlight the space up to the =.

   [image]
7. Then backspace to line everything up.

   [image]

** *I'm on mac, so the keys are going to be different for other OS.*

Comment: YES! This is precisely what I needed in my life! FYI to others, ⌥ is "Option key". The hotkey is ctrl for me on Linux.

Comment: I think the default key in windows is alt as well.

Comment: great!   but how to keep that when doing `reformat code` ?

Comment: @G_KOBELIEF Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Formatter Control -> Enable formatter markers in comments.