# PyCharm: Automatically align in-line comments

Tags: comments, pycharm, indentation, auto-indent

I use PyCharm 2016.2 to write my Python programs. Some of my in-line comments look a little messe:

```
code    # comment
code  # comment
more code  # comment
```

Is there a way to have PyCharm automatically align all in-line comments in a section or file on a vertical line. So it looks like this:

```
code       # comment
code       # comment
more code  # comment
```

Related to that: I tried doing it manually, but PyCharm sometimes messes up my indentation of comments, e.g., when copying code. How can I change that?

Comment: How did you align them in the first place?  Regardless of that you should try to avoid inline comments.  It is better to use a comment above multiple lines of code explaining what they do as a whole.  Look up PEP8.

Comment: I insert additional tabs to manually align the comments. Ok, I will keep that in mind and try to use fewer inline comments. In my opinion, there sometimes still helpful, though.

Comment: How to add such inline comments in Pycharm ? Everytime I do Shift+3, it changes the whole line of code into a line comment

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52560760/2532408) might help you

Answer (score -3):

In Pycharm, do this while your script is open: Click on `Code`, then click on `Reformat Code` (or use the shortcut). I tried it on your example and it worked.

Note: If you only want to reformat part of your script, first run your mouse over the desired portion of the script to select it. Then follow above procedure.

Comment: This is exactly what doesnt work; Atleast on the default settings.